# I am trying to generate a bar chart to compare number of authors for publications per year

Tags: networking, bar-chart, analysis

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FCkS.png)
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe5YT.png)

I have tried to set the y axis to be number of authors that reads in a column in my spreadsheet labeled number_of_authors, and my x axis to read in a year column from the same spreadsheet.  However I keep getting a shape error message even though the columns have the same number of lines.  Is it because it is the lists are not the same length somehow? I am still pretty new to programming.  I have tried almost everything I can think of.